# element.InvokeMember("Click") only works part of the time vb.net

Tags: html, vb.net, webbrowser-control, element

I'm trying to automate a webbrowser control. I've actually been working on this on and off for a few years and around a year ago this was working fine! I use the following code to click a button in the web browser control programatically;

```
 element = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("gogogo")
 If element IsNot Nothing Then
      element.InvokeMember("Click")
 End If
```

Now it clicks the same button every time I run the code (some of the other elements change but this is irrespective of the button). Half the time it works fine, no problems - the other half the time it seems to do nothing... I've tried editing the code to;

```
 element = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("gogogo")
 If element IsNot Nothing Then
      element.InvokeMember("Submit")
 End If
```

And even tried having both *Submit* and *Click* called one after another to no avail. Has something changed with webbrowser controls in the last year or so? Is there a more robust way of clicking buttons?

Here's the HTML element of the button;

```
<input id="gogogo" style="margin-bottom: 5px" class="gogogo btn btn-attack" name="submit" type="submit" onload="this.disabled=false;" value="Send attack">
```

Comment: I have not had such a problem yet. Do you have an example link?

Comment: I can't really share a link as the page in question is behind a log in. I can share the elements definition from chrome's inspect element if that would help?

Comment: If that's as close as you can get, I guess so.

Comment: @VisualVincent thanks, I've added this to the question.

Comment: Please add the CSS class too if possible.

Comment: How do I get access to that?

Comment: It's located within something like `<head><style type="text/css">...</style></head>`. In Chrome you can also view the entire source of a page by navigating to `view-source:<your website here>`, for example: `view-source:www.google.com`

Comment: @VisualVincent I might be wrong, but I can't seem to find this in the page source - might the page not have it?

Comment: Might be an external file... Anyhow, I'll test the button with your code later today. But I'm interested in what you use to click it. Timer? Thread? Other?

Comment: I've used both. When it's in a thread I have an if statement to invoke the Webbrowser control.

Comment: I have tested the code you gave me and it works all of the time, therefore the problem must lie in the page's code. If we cannot access it there's nothing more we on Stack Overflow can do. You'll have to test it yourself, inspect elements, attributes and scripts to see if anything might stop your button from performing it's action(s).